# Set State for variables inside object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
       per_name:'',
       per_email:'',
       person:{
           name:'',
           email:'',
           array:[]
        }
    }
}

this.setState({
 person:{
 name:this.state.per_name,
 email:this.state.per_email
}
})
```

I'm new to react if i try to setstate in this manner "per_name is not defined" error is thrown.
How should state be set in such a case??

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve]. In particular you need a `class` to wrap this and show the context of where you call `this.setState()`. Is this inside another method of the class?

Comment: Also read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips to debug your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow this practice for more clearance

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
       per_name:'',
       per_email:'',
       person:{
           name:'',
           email:'',
           array:[]
        }
    }
}

someMethod() {
   const {person, per_name, per_email} = this.state;
   person.name = per_name;
   person.email = per_email;
   this.setState({
       person
   });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should keep the non modified keys by using spread operator :

```
this.setState({
  ...this.state,
 person:{
 ...this.state.person,
 name:this.state.per_name,
 email:this.state.per_email
}
})
```